# How to write a sequential code between JOB1 and JOB2 in MapReduce framework?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a `MapReduce` application that includes 2 jobs. 
I need a small code run between *Job1* and *Job2*. In other words, a small code run on the final output of *Job1*, and all mappers in *Job2* be able to use output of this small code.

This small code does not need to be run in parallel. It is a sequential code that should be run in a single machine and write output in HDFS.

I want to know how to write a sequential code in my application code between *Job1* and *Job2* that will run on a single machine and read the output of *Job1* from HDFS and write its own output in HDFS as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Driver (main) class, after the execution of *Job1*, (typically a `JobClient.runJob(conf);` command) and before the first commands that set up *Job2*, use hadoop's `FileSystem` to get the output of *Job1* and set the input of *Job2*, like this:

```
//...run job1

BufferedWriter bw = null;
BufferedReader br = null;  
try {
  String job1outPath = "/job1/output/";
  Path job2in = new Path("/job2/in/oneFile.txt");
  bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fs.create(job2in,true)));            
  FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
  FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path(job1outPath));
  for (int i=0;i<status.length;i++){
     br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(status[i].getPath())));
     String line;
     while ((line = br.readLine())!= null){
         bw.write("whatever"); //process the output of job1 as you wish
         bw.newLine();
     }
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.println(e);
} finally {
  try{
    bw.close();
    br.close(); //not sure if you need this inside the for loop
  } catch (IOException io) {
    System.out.println(io);
  }
}

//optionally delete "/job1/output/*" here
//...run job2 using "/job2/in" as your input path
```

This will run sequentially in your master node. You can also use `System.out.println()` commands to see useful info in your terminal, if you wish.

Hope it compiles, I didn't pass it through an editor, but I'm sure you can get it to work.